# Python dictionary deepcopy

Tags: python, dictionary, deep-copy

I was wondering in how does exactly deepcopy work in the following context:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def copyExample:
    self.myDict = {}
    firstPosition = "First"
    firstPositionContent = ["first", "primero"]
    secondPosition = "Second"
    secondPositionContent = ["second"]
    self.myDict[firstPosition] = firstPositionContent 
    self.myDict[secondPosition] = secondPositionContent
    return deepcopy(self.myDict)

def addExample(self):
    copy =  self.copyExample()
    copy["Second"].add("segundo")
```

Does it return the reference to the lists I have in the dictionary? Or does it work as I expect and copy every list in a new list with a different reference?

I know what a deep copy is (so there is no need to explain the difference between deep and shallow) but I am wondering if it works as I expect it to do and therefore do not change the instance variable when I use `addExample()`.

Comment: Did you print the two dictionaries to see if they're different?  What did you see?  Were they different?  If so, the copy has a new list to which you added an element.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) makes it pretty clear that you're getting new copies, not references. Deepcopy creates deep copies for built in types, with various exceptions and that you can add custom copy operations to your user-defined objects to get deep copy support for them as well. If you're not sure, well that's what unit testing is for.

Comment: I dont think it states built in types, it states that it does “copy”  the pickable objects... Does that mean I would get a new list reference?

Comment: Deepcopy has a short list of exceptions.  Everything else is copied.
"This module does not copy types like module, method, stack trace, stack frame, file, socket, window, array, or any similar types."  You get a new list.  Not a reference to the list but a new list.  Print the two dictionaries from your example and look at them.

Answer (score 3):

I know it isn't answering your question but I think it's noteworthy for people looking at this question.

If the data you're copying is simple in nature deepcopy might be overkill. With simple in nature I mean if your data is representable as Json. Let me illustrate with code:

I've used http://www.json-generator.com/ to get some sample json data.

```
def deepCopyList(inp):
    for vl in inp:
        if isinstance(vl, list):
            yield list(deepCopyList(vl))
        elif isinstance(vl, dict):
            yield deepCopyDict(vl)
        else:
            yield vl

            
def deepCopyDict(inp):
    outp = inp.copy()
    for ky, vl in outp.iteritems():
        if isinstance(vl, dict):
            outp[ky] = deepCopyDict(vl)      
        elif isinstance(vl, list):
            outp[ky] = list(deepCopyList(vl))  
    return outp
    
def simpleDeepCopy(inp):
    if isinstance(inp, dict):
        return deepCopyDict(inp)
    elif isinstance(inp, list):
        return deepCopyList(inp)
    else:
        return inp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import simplejson as json
    import time
    from copy import deepcopy
    fl = open('sample.json', 'r')
    sample = json.load(fl)
    start = time.time()
    for _ in xrange(10000):
        tmp = simpleDeepCopy(sample)
    end = time.time()
    print 'simpleDeepCopy: ' + str(end - start)
    start = time.time()
    for _ in xrange(10000):
        tmp = deepcopy(sample)
    end = time.time()
    print 'copy.deepcopy: ' + str(end - start)
```

output:

```
simpleDeepCopy: 0.0132050514221
copy.deepcopy: 2.66142916679

simpleDeepCopy: 0.0128579139709
copy.deepcopy: 2.60736298561
```

Comment: "With simple in nature I mean if your data is representable as Json" - that's a wrong statement: even some simple, "JSON-able" object might need `.deepcopy()` to avoid references. Try this: `a = {1:'A', 2:['a', 'b', 'c'], 3:'Z'}; b = a.copy(); a[2].append('d'); print b`

Comment: If the data is representable as JSON, why not just use `json.loads(json.dumps(data))`..?