# Deep copy of a dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to make a deep copy of a `dict` in python. Unfortunately the `.deepcopy()` method doesn't exist for the `dict`. How do I do that?

```
>>> my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> my_copy = my_dict.deepcopy()
Traceback (most recent calll last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'
>>> my_copy = my_dict.copy()
>>> my_dict['a'][2] = 7
>>> my_copy['a'][2]
7
```

The last line should be `3`.

I would like that modifications in `my_dict` don't impact the snapshot `my_copy`.

How do I do that? The solution should be compatible with Python 3.x.

Comment: I don't know if it's a duplicate, but this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838642/python-dictionary-deepcopy is awfully close.

Answer (score 858, accepted):

How about:

```
import copy
d = { ... }
d2 = copy.deepcopy(d)
```

Python 2 or 3:

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:30:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import copy
>>> my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> my_copy = copy.deepcopy(my_dict)
>>> my_dict['a'][2] = 7
>>> my_copy['a'][2]
3
>>>
```

Comment: Indeed that works for the oversimplified example I gave. My keys are not numbers but objects. If I read the copy module documentation, I have to declare a __copy__()/__deepcopy__() method for the keys. Thank you very much for leading me there!

Comment: Is there any difference in Python 3.2 and 2.7 codes? They seem identical to me. If so, would be better a single block of code and a statement "Works for both Python 3 and 2"

Comment: It's also worth mentioning `copy.deepcopy` isn't thread safe. Learned this the hard way. On the other hand, depending on your use case, `json.loads(json.dumps(d))` _is_ thread safe, and works well.

Comment: @rob you should post that comment as an answer.  It is a viable alternative.  The thread safety nuance is an important distinction.

Comment: Of course, I guess one could also wrap `copy.deepcopy` in a homegrown thread safe function?

Comment: @BuvinJ The issue is that `json.loads` doesn't solve the problem for all use cases where python `dict` attributes are not JSON serializable. It may help those who are only dealing with simple data structures, from an API for example, but I don't think it's enough of a solution to fully answer the OP's question.

Comment: @rob, I understand the limitation.  Thanks for posting your comment.  You may have saved me some trouble.

Comment: another fun fact: deepcopy of dict does not always preserve the order of elements: `d = dict() ;
for n in range(8): d[(n,n+1)] = n ;
assert d.keys() == copy.deepcopy(d).keys() 
`

Comment: @rob Please can you convince me that JSON.dumps is threadsafe? This answer seems to contradict that hypothesis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23781650

Comment: What does the lack of thread safety mean here? i.e., would it be safe to copy `my_dict` from multiple threads, as long as `my_dict` isn't modified in the process?

Comment: "thread safety" is a rather meaningless term, unless you use its opposite, "not thread safe". Thread safety implies expectations of behavior, but it doesn't detail *which* behavior. The thread safety a library author has in mind might not be the same a library user has in mind. For instance, is it enough that a collection doesn't corrupt itself if used on multiple threads? Do you need a check against `count > 0` followed by an implicit read of the first item to be consistent? In general, *reads* are thread safe as long as reading something doesn't have side-effects.

Comment: `json.loads(json.dumps(d))` makes integer key to str
`{1: {2: 3}, 3: [1, 2, 3]}` -> `{'1': {'2': 3}, '3': [1, 2, 3]}`

Answer (score 73):

***dict.copy()*** is a shallow copy function for dictionary 

***id*** is built-in function that gives you the address of variable

First you need to understand "why is this particular problem is happening?"

```
In [1]: my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}

In [2]: my_copy = my_dict.copy()

In [3]: id(my_dict)
Out[3]: 140190444167808

In [4]: id(my_copy)
Out[4]: 140190444170328

In [5]: id(my_copy['a'])
Out[5]: 140190444024104

In [6]: id(my_dict['a'])
Out[6]: 140190444024104
```

The address of the list present in both the dicts for key 'a' is pointing to same location. 
Therefore when you change value of the list in my_dict, the list in my_copy changes as well.

---

**Solution for data structure mentioned in the question:**

```
In [7]: my_copy = {key: value[:] for key, value in my_dict.items()}

In [8]: id(my_copy['a'])
Out[8]: 140190444024176
```

Or you can use deepcopy as mentioned above.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for nested dictionaries.  deepcopy is preferable for that reason.

Comment: @CharlesPlager Agreed! But you should also notice that list slicing doesn't work on dict `value[:]`. The solution was for the particular data structure mentioned in the question rather than a universal solution.

Comment: 2nd solution for dict comprehension would not work with nested lists as values

```
>>> my_copy = {k:v.copy() for k,v in my_dict.items()}
>>> id(my_copy["a"])
4427452032
>>> id(my_dict["a"])
4427460288
>>> id(my_copy["a"][0])
4427469056
>>> id(my_dict["a"][0])
4427469056
```

Comment: This is the bets solution for people who do not want to or can not use extra libraries. I am using python in LaTex environment, due to which I could not afford to use a single extra library. So, this solution works like a charm for me. Thanks @theBuzzyCoder

Answer (score 69):

Python 3.x

```
from copy import deepcopy

# define the original dictionary
original_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': {'c': 4, 'd': 5, 'e': 6}}

# make a deep copy of the original dictionary
new_dict = deepcopy(original_dict)

# modify the dictionary in a loop
for key in new_dict:
    if isinstance(new_dict[key], dict) and 'e' in new_dict[key]:
        del new_dict[key]['e']

# print the original and modified dictionaries
print('Original dictionary:', original_dict)
print('Modified dictionary:', new_dict)
```

Which would yield:

```
Original dictionary: {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': {'c': 4, 'd': 5, 'e': 6}}
Modified dictionary: {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': {'c': 4, 'd': 5}}
```

Without `new_dict = deepcopy(original_dict)`, 'e' element is unable to be removed.

Why? Because if the loop was `for key in original_dict`, and an attempt is made to modify original_dict, a RuntimeError would be observed:

```
"RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"
```

So in order to modify a dictionary within an iteration, a copy of the dictionary must be used.

Here is an example function that removes an element from a dictionary:

```
def remove_hostname(domain, hostname):
    domain_copy = deepcopy(domain)
    for domains, hosts in domain_copy.items():
        for host, port in hosts.items():
           if host == hostname:
                del domain[domains][host]
    return domain
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253799/rob) suggested a good alternative to `copy.deepcopy()` if you are planning to create standard APIs for your data (database or web request json payloads).

```py
>>> import json
>>> my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(my_dict))
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

This approach is also thread safe.
But it only works for jsonifiable (serializable) objects like `str`, `dict`, `list`, `int`, `float`, and `None`.
Sometimes that jsonifiable constraint can be a good thing because it forces you to make your data structures compliant with standard database fixture and web request formats (for creating best-practice APIs).

If your data structures don't work directly with `json.dumps` (for example `datetime` objects and your custom classes) they will be need to be coerced into a string or other standard type before serializing with `json.dumps()`.
And you'll need to run a custom deserializer as well after `json.loads()`:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> my_dict = {'a': (1,), 'b': dt(2023, 4, 9).isoformat()}
>>> d = json.loads(json.dumps(my_dict))
>>> d
{'a': [1], 'b': '2023-04-09T00:00:00'}
>>> for k in d:
...     try:
...         d[k] = dt.fromisoformat(d[k])
...     except:
...         pass
>>> d
{'a': [1], 'b': datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 9, 0, 0)}
```

Of course you need to do the serialization and deserialization on special objects recursively.
Sometimes that's a good thing.
This process normalizes all your objects to types that are directly serializable (for example `tuple`s become `list`s) and you can be sure they'll match a reproducable data schema (for relational database storage).

And it's thread safe. The builtin `copy.deepcopy()` is **NOT** thread safe! If you use `deepcopy` within `async` code that can crash your program or corrupt your data unexpectedly long after you've forgotten about your code.

Comment: Please explain why it's thread-safe. Becasuse [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) doesn't say that those methods are thread-safe.

Comment: I think @Rob is right, those functions merely create two new objects without reusing any of the data from the original object. And the intermediate str object is deleted. Constructing new built-in types is always thread safe. But now that I say it out loud, perhaps you're concerned that the mutable objects might be modified during `json.dumps()`. I'd have to do some testing to see if dicts and lists are locked while you're iterating through them. I thought `iter`s were thread safe.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Python dicts and lists are thread-safe, even for write operations, but this code is only doing reads from dicts and lists, so that makes it even more obviously thread safe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6955678/623735

Comment: So if I follow your reasoning, `copy.deepcopy()` is also thread-safe. Then why is this answer more relevant? Or what makes `copy.deepcopy()` not thread-safe?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire It's not better, just different. I like knowing how to do things many different ways so I can choose the right approach for my application. And I can remember and debug this one much more easily than deepcopy. Deepcopy is doing a lot of magic in C that I can't control on configure. Serialization (jsonifying) gives me more control and visibility into what is going on.

Comment: It's just that your first sentence in the answer seem to indicate that `copy.deepcopy()` isn't thread-safe "@Rob suggested a thread safe alternative to copy.deepcopy():" while your answer is thread-safe. Actually none are thread-safe. So I'd like that you remove your assertion that your answer is thread-safe.

Comment: Good point! I'll clarify the answer.