# When I assign a dict to another variable, why does Python update both dicts?

Tags: python

How to avoid the following while using dictionaries

```
a={'b':1}
c=a
c.update({'b':2})
print a # {'b':2}
print c # {'b':2}
```

Comment: Here 'a' and 'b' are pointing to the same memory location.Hence a change in 'a' reflects in 'b'.
print(id(a),id(b)) and see that both have the same id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the dictionary `copy`-method. Like so:

```
>>> a = {'b': 1}
>>> c = a.copy()
>>> c.update({'b': 2})
>>> print a
{'b': 1}
>>> print c
{'b': 2}
>>>
```

Please note that this is a *shallow* copy. Thus, if you have mutable objects (dictionaries, lists, etc) in your dictionary, it will copy a reference to those objects. In such cases you should use [copy.deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy). Example below:

```
>>> import copy
>>> a = {'b': {'g': 4}}
>>> c = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> c['b'].update({'g': 15})
>>> print a
{'b': {'g': 4}}
>>> print c
{'b': {'g': 15}}
```

Comment: I have some thing like a={'b':'{"g": 4}'} In this case can i use only .copy()

Comment: no, a['b'] and c['b'] will refer to the same directory, use deepcopy().

Answer (score 2):

Obviously your question has been answered. But what might help here is to correct your mental model.

In Python, variables don't **store** values, they **name** values. Check out [this article](http://python.net/~mwh/hacks/objectthink.html) for the example of the statue pointing at the hotel.

A quick and easy way to check if you're referencing the same object is to print the ID of the variable:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> b = a
>>> print(id(a), id(b))
12345 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
c = a.copy()
```

Also see this one:
[Deep copy of a dict in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105517/deep-copy-of-a-dict-in-python)

It allows you to copy by value lists inside of your dict

Answer (score 0):

Both variables `a` and `c` reference the same dict object, so when you mutate it through the variable `c` then the *underlying* dict object is changed. As `a` points to the same object, those changes will be visible from there too.

If you want to have both `a` and `c` reference a dictionary which are independent of each other, then you need to *copy* the dictionary, so that you actually receive two separate objects. You can do that by using [`dict.copy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy):

```
a = {'b': 1}
c = a.copy()
c.update({'b': 2})

print a # {'b': 1}
print c # {'b': 2}
```

Note that this will only create a shallow copy, so if the dictionary contains mutable objects—like another dictionary, a list or some other object—then you all copies will again reference the same underlying objects (just like your original code). If you want to avoid that, you can create [a deep copy of the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105517/deep-copy-of-a-dict-in-python):

```
import copy
a = {'b': {'c': 1}}
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
b['b'].update({'c': 2})

print a # {'b': {'c': 1}}
print b # {'b': {'c': 2}}
```

Comment: I have some thing like a={'b':'{"g": 4}'} In this case can i use only .copy()

Comment: As mentioned, if you store mutable objects like another dictionary, you will need to create a deep copy.