# Concerning python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

My question  is :
I have a function in python which takes a dictionary and a string as input. This dictionary has strings as keys as lists as values. In function dictionaries lists are changed - entries removed as they are used until first empty list in values is hit. For one run it works well, but when this function is in a for loop changing only input string and using the very same dictionary, with each iteration original input dictionary is changed. This is despite in function by the first step I create a new dictionary setting it equal to input and make all changes on that new dictionary. Could you give me a hint of what is wrong? Why original dictionary is affected? Also I got the same when I create a new list in for loop before function and pass this new list as input.

Here is an actual code :

```
#reading an input file 
x=open('graph .txt')
data=[line.strip() for line in x.readlines()]

gr=[s.split(' -> ') for s in data]

#creating a graph 
graph={}

for i in gr:
    graph[i[0]]=list(i[1])

for val in graph.values():
    if ',' in val:
        val = val.remove(',')
cycle=[]

nums=graph.keys()

# function changing dictionary 
def path(start,graph):
    cycle=[]
    graph111=graph
    cycle.append(start)
    while graph111[start]!=[]:
        move=graph111[start]
        if move==[]:
            break
        if len(move)>1:
            n=''.join(move[0])
            start=n
            cycle.append(n)
        else:
             p=''.join(move)
             start=p
             cycle.append(p)
        move.remove(move[0])
    return ('->'.join(cycle))
# for loop:
for num in nums:
    c=path(num,graph)
    cycles.append(c)
```

input looks like this:

```
 0 -> 3
 1 -> 0
 2 -> 1,6
 3 -> 2
 4 -> 2
 5 -> 4
 6 -> 5,8
 7 -> 9
 8 -> 7
 9 -> 6
```

Comment: Please include the actual code.

Comment: If you posted relevant part of your code...you would save the trouble on yourself this big paragraph ..

Comment: its not sufficient to copy the dictionary. The lists in the dictionary need to be copied too. Try `copy.deepcopy`, e.g., `mydictcopy=copy.deepcopy(mydict)`.

Comment: _"I create a new dictionary setting it equal to input"_ can you tell us how you do that?

Comment: I added a code question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actual code it is difficult to understand what's going on in your question, but let me make a guess: you have something like this:

```
def do_smth(dc):
    new_dict = dc
    new_dict['haha']='hohoho'

this_dict={}
do_smth(this_dict)
```

Then you see that `this_dict` has been changed. This is because you pass a reference to `this_dict` when invoke your function and thus your function is able to modify `this_dict`. Note also, that assignment does not make a copy, so `new_dict = ds` does not help you. You have to write `new_dict = ds.copy()` to make a copy. Moreover, if your dictionary has other mutable objects as values, `.copy()` will not be enough: you'll need to use `copy.deepcopy()` instead, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105517/deep-copy-of-a-dict-in-python).

You can read the details [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ischurov/pythonhse/blob/master/Lecture%207.ipynb#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) (in Russian).

Comment: `D.copy() -> a shallow copy of D` ... is not sufficient. a deepcopy is needed to also copy the inner lists.

Comment: @tdelaney, you may be right, but without the code i'm not sure. However, i'll update an answer per your comment.

Comment: I added a code to question. That function I want to use in for loop. You were correct, this is similar to what I intended. Thank you! Deepcopy is what I need here.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating a new list or dictionary by an assignment in python:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=a
>>> b[1]=5
>>> b
[1, 5, 3]
>>> a
[1, 5, 3]
```

To copy a list, you can use the slice notation:

```
>>> c=a[:]
>>> c
[1, 5, 3]
>>> a[1]=10
>>> a
[1, 10, 3]
>>> c
[1, 5, 3]
```

For dictionaries, see [Deep copy of a dict in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105517/deep-copy-of-a-dict-in-python).
For more complex data types and general hints, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html