# Python: Dictionary changing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

For some reason when I modify mydict2 it changes the contents of mydict

Here is my code:

```
mydict = {1:'a', 2:'b'}
mydict2 = mydict
mydict2[1] = 'c'
print(mydict2)
```

If you try this, it outputs `{1: 'c', 2: 'b'}`

It should output `{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}` and when you do `print(mydict)` it should output `{1: 'c', 2: 'b'}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)

Comment: No, the dictionary is changing

Comment: Not sure why though @MoinuddinQuadri

Comment: Because `mydict` and `mydict2` are both pointing to the same object.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `mydict` and `mydict2` are two different names for the same dictionary. Assignment does not create a copy.

Comment: Oh ok thanks @leaf that has really helped

Comment: This is because `mydict` and `mydict2` are references to the same dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mydict` and `mydict2` are both pointing to the same object in memory. When either one changes, the other does as well. They references to the same dictionary.

It is not enough to use the assignment operator to make a proper copy.  If you want `mydict2` to point to a copy of the dictionary `mydict` points to, you need to tell Python to *explicitly* make a copy:

```
>>> mydict = {1:'a', 2:'b'}
>>> mydict2 = mydict.copy()
>>> mydict2[1] = 'c'
>>> mydict
{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
>>> mydict2
{1: 'c', 2: 'b'}
>>>
```

Note however that this method will fail if you have a nested dictionary structure. You'd need to use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) in that case.

Answer (score 1):

`mydict` and `mydict2` are both references to the same object.

So changes to `mydict` or `mydict2` will change the same object, and therefore it looks like changing one of them is changing the other.

Answer (score 0):

You should use function copy:

```
from copy import copy
mydict = {1:'a', 2:'b'}
mydict2 = copy(mydict)
mydict2[1] = 'c'
print(mydict2)
```

There are two links for the same object. If you want to have two objects, you should copy your dict

Comment: Can you elaborate on/explain this answer a bit? Why should `copy` be used?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting mydic2 equal to the object mydict. When you mutate mydict2, it will change the contents of mydict1.

Try using copy or copy.deepcopy as seen here: [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

See this thread for an example: [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105517/deep-copy-of-a-dict-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

mydict and mydict2 both reference the same dictionary, so when you change one, you change the other one too.