# Converting Python dict to class __init__ **kwargs?

Tags: python

I want to create two instance of class , and send dict to **init** ,
but why the first class instance reference second class dict ?

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        self.k = kwargs


initDict = {'PP':{'a':1}}
newC1 = initDict.copy()
newC1['PP']['b'] = 2
qq1 = Test(**newC1)

newC2 = initDict.copy()
newC2['PP']['b'] = 999
qq2 = Test(**newC2)

print('---------------')
print(qq1.k)
print(qq2.k)
```

there is the result

```
{'PP': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
{'PP': {'a': 1, 'b': 999}}
---------------
{'PP': {'a': 1, 'b': 999}}
{'PP': {'a': 1, 'b': 999}}
```

Comment: `initDict.copy()` is a shallow copy. The nested dict isn't copied.

Comment: ^This. Try comparing id of newC1 and newC2 (different, because `.copy()`) and id of newC1['PP'] and newC2['PP'] (same, nested dict is kept the same way)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica there must be an appropriate duplicate for this.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica is right. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105517/deep-copy-of-a-dict-in-python) and deepcopy your `initDict`