# Select json object by position?

Tags: python, json

This is my code:

```
response = requests.get(url,params=datas)
data = response.json()
price=data["bids"]
print(price)
```

Output of the code:

`{'31833.94000000': '0.02832100', '31833.93000000': '0.01291000', '31833.91000000': '0.09935100', '31833.90000000': '0.10243500', '31833.52000000': '0.01751100', '31833.38000000': '0.03296200', '31831.66000000': '0.00148000', '31831.24000000': '0.17640200', '31831.23000000': '0.84000000', '31830.79000000': '0.00044800', '31830.02000000': '0.70980400', ...`

- Data changes every time I receive them.
- How can I copy only the first element?

Comment: This is just a guess, since I did not quite understand your question neither the context, but what you might be looking is a deep copy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5105554/4868875

Comment: That is not a "json object", that is the *result* of deserializing JSON into *python objects*, in this case, you have a `dict`. Note, `dict` objects maintain insertion order, however, the JSON standard says that JSON objects, which is what the `dict` comes from *are unordered*. Does the API really use the *order* of the JSON obejct?

Comment: In the api page: This API provides with a sorted list (in descending order) of bids and asks. They are ordered from the newest to oldest price, there is a way to copy only the first price so i can make an order with it?

Comment: @Aldo: What's shown in your question is not a list, it's a Python dictionary which corresponds to a JSON "object" which is "An _unordered_ set of name/value pairs." (see [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the json into an ordered dictionary (odict) and then read the value by index.

http://dl.ubnt.com/RouterStationChallenge/PyCI/docs/PyCI/odict.html

Answer (score 0):

It worked, thank you

```
    response = requests.get(url,params=datas)
    data = response.json()
    price=collections.OrderedDict(data["bids"])
    first=list(price)[:1]
    print(first)
```

but there is a fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

if we assume by the first element you mean: '31833.94000000': '0.02832100', you can store it as a tuple like this:

```
first_element = [(k,v) for (k,v) in data["bids"].items()][0]
```