# Why doesn't deepcopy work on a python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to achieve deepcopy in dictionaries?

My original code :

```
li1 = ['Column_6', 'Column_11']
delimiters = ['a','b','c','d']
inner_dict = dict.fromkeys(delimiters,[0,0])
delim_dict = dict.fromkeys(li1 ,None)
for k,v in delim_dict.items():
    delim_dict[k] = copy.deepcopy(inner_dict)
```

print (delim_dict) gives

```
{'Column_6': {'a': [0, 0], 'b': [0, 0], 'c': [0, 0], 'd': [0, 0]},
 'Column_11': {'a': [0, 0], 'b': [0, 0], 'c': [0, 0], 'd': [0, 0]}}
```

```
delim_dict['Column_6']['a'][0]=5
print (delim_dict)
```

gives

```
{'Column_6': {'a': [5, 0], 'b': [5, 0], 'c': [5, 0], 'd': [5, 0]},
 'Column_11': {'a': [0, 0], 'b': [0, 0], 'c': [0, 0], 'd': [0, 0]}}
```

Why keys b,c,d are updated with [5, 0] in spite of deepcopy?

I am able to achieve result with the Modified code :

```
li1 = ['Column_6', 'Column_11']
delimiters = ['a','b','c','d']
#inner_dict = dict.fromkeys(delimiters,[0,0])
delim_dict = dict.fromkeys(li1 ,None)
for k,v in delim_dict.items():
    delim_dict[k] = {}
    for delim in delimiters:
        delim_dict[k][delim]=[0,0]
```

But, how can i achieve the same result with deep copy or is there any other efficient way?

Note:
I tried following this link:
[Deep copy of a dict in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105517/deep-copy-of-a-dict-in-python)
No luck.

Comment: So you want to have a deep copy of the dictionary delimiters? As i see no `data` defined here

Comment: inner_dict has data {'a': [0, 0], 'b': [0, 0], 'c': [0, 0], 'd': [0, 0]} right? Sorry if i am missing your question

Comment: To copy a dictionary you do `import copy` `a = {1:2, 3:4}` `b = copy.deepcopy(a)`

Comment: You can also put the `data` variable in your question so we know what to expect.
If i run your code it will show that `data` is not initialized and we may assume wrongly what the data inside `data` will be

Comment: I did :copy.deepcopy(inner_dict) . Not working.

Comment: Don't use the same list object as all `inner_dict` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same list object as all `inner_dict` values, and `deepcopy` respects that and keeps it that way. Which you clearly don't want. So don't do that in the first place. Do `inner_dict = {d: [0, 0] for d in delimiters}` instead.

As [the `fromkeys` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) says:

> All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for *value* to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
li1 = ['Column_6', 'Column_11']
delimiters = ['a','b','c','d']
inner_dict = dict.fromkeys(delimiters,[0,0])
delim_dict = dict.fromkeys(li1 ,None)
for k,v in delim_dict.items():
    delim_dict[k] = {key: value[:] for key, value in inner_dict.items()}

print (delim_dict)

delim_dict['Column_6']['a'][0]=5
print (delim_dict)
```

with [:] splicing and no use of the copy module

Comment: I guess you can do that, but having that bad `inner_dict` at all just seems needlessly dangerous.