# Key removed from original dict despite dict.copy()

Tags: python, django, dictionary, lambda, session-variables

I'm recently experimenting with session variables instead of writing everything in base.
I'm building an app for counter sales (cart, user, customer session variables).
After the order and its items are saved in DB, I want to save the customer and clear its related session variablesin **request.session['customers']** dict list.

```
def save_customer(request, store):
    # save only customers != Client Magasin
    customers = request.session['customers'].copy()
    print(customers)
    current_customer = list(filter(
       lambda i: i['user'] == request.user.pk and i['store'] == store, customers))[0]
    id = current_customer.pop('id')
    nom = current_customer['nom']
    if nom != 'Client Magasin':
        current_customer.pop('store')
        current_customer.pop('user')
        customer = Customer.objects.create(**current_customer)
        # return Customer for adding it to order
        return customer
    else:
        # return Client Magasin
        return Customer.objects.get(pk=1)
```

When I print out **request.session['customers']** I can see ID, STORE and USER keys. But after the lambda, those keys are removed from the original **request.session['customers']**

I know that because further in my code, I wan't to filter again this list

```
def remove_same_customer(request):
    customers_list = request.session['customers'].copy()
    print(customers_list)
    # new_customers = list(filter(
    #     lambda i:  i['store'] != request.session['cart_warehouse'] and i['user'] != 
        request.user, customers_list))
    # request.session['customers'] = new_customers
    # request.session.modified = True
```

I have commented the 4 last lines because they trigger an error because ID, STORE and USER keys can't be found. This is confirmed by using **print(customers_list)**

what am I doing wrong ?
PS : dunno if dict.copy() is useful in my case but I tried this after the error raised.

Comment: Since you access keys on the elements of ``customers``, it's a *nested* dictionary. `.copy()` creates a shallow copy, i.e. only copies the outer dictionary; the inner dictionaries still are identical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep copy of a dict in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105517/deep-copy-of-a-dict-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

Comment: Oh yes ! It was my mistake. I had read about deepcopy() a few days ago and it slipped my mind. Thank you to you 2