# How to update a list with one item to multiple in JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary same dictionary I want it in 5 times and append to the list

I tried this

```
dict = {
        "text":"Hi",
        "feedback":""
}

for i in range(0,5):
      json.dump(dict, file)
```

Ex: -  I'm passing this list

```
"items": [
        {
            "text": "Hi",
            "feedback": ""
        }
    ]
```

Expected output:

```
"items": [
        {
            "text": "Hi",
            "feedback": ""
        },
        {
            "text": "Hi",
            "feedback": ""
        },
        {
            "text": "Hi",
            "feedback": ""
        },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have dict as `dict1={"text": "Hi","feedback": ""}`  and you need a list with 5 times of same dict then go for `[dict1 for i in range(0,5)]`

Comment: Since this repeats **the same dict** in the list, something like `dict_list[0]["text"] = "Hello"` will change all entries, not just the first one. [Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy) or [deepcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105517/deep-copy-of-a-dict-in-python) the dict as needed.

Comment: then you have to go for 
`for I in range(0,5):
    dict1["text"]='updatewithyourstring'
    list_x.append(dict1)`