Copy value from one dictionary to another
I have a situation where I have several very large lists of dictionaries and dictionaries containing vast amounts of data built elsewhere that is delivered in very large json objects. I need to take information from this large data heap and construct a new list of dictionaries containing a subset of data. But the resulting new dictionaries can not have any references to the old dictionaries from where the data was taken.
Example
consider the following two data sources (very simple example on the real data we are trying to work with):
 list_1 = [{ "id": "12", "b": 33,   "d": "rty" }, 
           { "id": "22", "b": 135,  "d": "jjj" },
           { "id": "32", "b": 1,    "d": "trt" },
           { "id": "42", "b": 1355, "d": "ast" },]

 dict_2 = { "12" : { "id": "12", "c": "ada" },
            "22" : { "id": "22", "c": "pklm" },
            "32" : { "id": "32", "c": "pppf" },  
            "42" : { "id": "42", "c": "eeef" },}  

we then want to build a new list of dictionaries from this data. The rule is that for each dict in list_a where value b is less then 40 we want to build a new dictionary with the same id and the values c and d and add this new dict to a new list.
 newlist = [{ "id": "12", "c": "ada", "d": "rty" },
            { "id": "32", "c": "pppf", "d": "trt" },  

if we simply do this:
newlist = []
for x in list_1:
  if x["b"] < 40:
    dict = {"id": x["id"],
            "d": x["d"],
            "c": (dict_2[x["id"]])["c"] }
    newlist.append(dict)

then the dictionaries in newlist will contain references to list_1 and dict_2. Which is all and good when you want to save on memory the classic way i suppose.
But in our case we do not want the references. We need to be able to remove list_1 and dict_2 from memory after newlist has been made so we save in on memory usage that way. Newlist need to continue to exist in memory. List_1 and dict_2 are very very large and the resulting newlist is but a fraction in size.
When we check with the module memory_profiler we see that Python do not release the memory used by list_1 and dict_2 because the values taken from these two sources are then used to set values in newlist and because of this the two sources still need to be in memory because of the references. :/
How can this be done in Python? Can it be done in Python? How can we get a true copy and not a reference to the source? Right now we are leaning towards writing newdict to a file, wipe everything and then reload newdict from the file into memory and continue from there. But that seem like a rather crude solution.
Any ideas?

if the dict's values are actually immutable objects like int and str objects, the code should work perfectly fine

it might be a problem that you use dict as a variable name, which shadows the builtin dict type, but I don't see how this leads to the behaviour you describe

Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/5105517/2422776

have you tye deleting the objects and calling the garbage collector to see what happend?

@toyotaSupra The pydictionary tag is for the third-party PyDictionary library. This question has nothing to do with that.

There are no references to list_1 and list_2 in your result. You're just copying leaf values.

Are you sure you deleted the variables list_1 and list_2 when you were profiling? Maybe you have other variables referring to them.

"When we check with the module memory_profiler we see that Python do not release the memory used by list_1 and dict_2 because the values taken from these two sources are then used to set values in newlist and because of this the two sources still need to be in memory because of the references. :/" IThat isn't what's happening with your example code here.

If you want to break the reference and ensure that no memory is held by the dictionaries, you can use the deep copy concept.
Try modifying your existing code with the usage of copy.deepcopy() after importing the copy into your python file
import copy
   
#instead of "d": x["d"], use

"d": copy.deepcopy(x["d"])

#do the same for all the list

Then you can delete the previous list if you dont want them to retain.
hope it solves the problem.
