# How can I leave the original dictionary unchanged, when editing a the new dict

Tags: python, immutability

I just start to learn coding in Python.
Please allow me to ask a stupid question which has bothered me for a long time.

```
g={1:'a',2:'b',3:["k",'c'],4:'d'}

gt=g    

gt[3].remove('c')
```

How can I leave the g unchanged?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838642/python-dictionary-deepcopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) for this. And since your copying a dictionary that contains a list and you want to edit that list, you should use deepcopy:

```
from copy import deepcopy

g={1:'a',2:'b',3:["k",'c'],4:'d'}

gt=copy.deepcopy(g)  

gt[3].remove('c')
```